# Class method that makes an object from multiple arguments

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In Pharo I want to create a Class Method that creates a new person object and sets a name and age all in one method (two arguments)

```
Object subclass: #Person
        instanceVariableNames: 'name age'
        classVariableNames: ''
        category: '...'
```

However I am unable to access the instance variables within the class method.

```
name: n : age: a
        "Class method that creates a Person Object and defines its name and age"

        | person1 |
        person1 := self new.
        person1 name := n. "Unable to compile past this point due to red syntax highlighting
        person1 age := a.
        ^person1.
```

My goal is to be able to call:

```
aPerson := Person name: 'Pharo' age: '4'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot set *instance* variables from a *class* method.

To solve your problem you could create accessor methods for your instance variables (on the instance side..) and call those from your class side constructor method:

```
name: n age: a
    "Class method that creates a Person Object and defines its name and age"

    | person1 |
    person1 := self new.
    person1 name: n.
    person1 age: a.
    ^ person1
```

But for this purpose it is common to code a single *instance* method to set all the variables and preface its name with *set*, followed by the variable names:

```
setName: aString age: aNumber
    personName := aString.
    age := aNumber.
    ^ self
```

Now your constructor *class* method would look like this:

```
name: aString  age: aNumber
    ^ self new setName: aString age: aNumber
```

Comment: and there is a reason for this: Person (the class) is an Object, Person new (the instance) is another one. In smalltalk, instances variables are private, you can't directly mutate the instance variables of another object, even if you are the own class of this object... You have to ask it to kindly do so by sending a message - unless some introspective primitives are available to do it... Inquire how Newspeak addressed this problem.